# HTTPS Post request to login C#

Tags: c#, authentication, http-post

1 am trying to login into a website to a poker website using post request. but i am not getting the correct response. I am getting the source of the original login page itself.

I know the credentials are correct because they work manually.

Below is the snippet for trying to log in. As per my understanding the response source code should be that of a successful login.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string username = "####";
    string password = "########";
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://ftrpoker.com/login.html");
    request.Method = "POST";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII))
    {
        writer.Write("USERNAME=" + username + "&PASSWORD=" + password);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Comment: Make sure that your request is being sent to the right **server side** page. (perhaps `login.php` or `login.asp` etc.)

You can follow your request using the `Networking` tab in chrome/firefox developer tools

Comment: The page is correct. But I will check Firefox to see if the post parameters are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a similar problem. Try using RemoteCertificateValidationCallback attached to ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback.

Something like this:

```
private static bool ValidateRemoteCertificate(object sender,X509Certificate certificate,X509Chain chain,SslPolicyErrors policyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```

Solution from:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2acefdc1-be7f-4dc1-a5f0-61cceed2958c/posting-using-post-from-c-over-https?forum=netfxbcl